# Convert R JSON Twitter data to list

Tags: r

When using SearchTwitter, I converted to dataframe and then exported to JSON. However, all the text is in one line, etc (sample below). I need to separate so that each tweet is its own.

```
phish <- searchTwitteR('phish', n = 5, lang = 'en')
phishdf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(phish, as.data.frame))
exportJson <-toJSON(phishdf)
write(exportJson, file = "phishdf.json")
json_phishdf <- fromJSON(file="phishdf.json")
```

I tried converting to a list and am wondering if maybe converting to a data frame is a mistake.

However, for a list, I tried:

```
newlist['text']=phish[[1]]$getText()
```

But this will just give me the text for the first tweet. Is there a way to iterate over the entire data set, maybe in a for loop?

```
{"text":["@ilazer @abbijacobson I do feel compelled to say that I phind phish awphul... sorry, Abbi!","@phish This on-sale was an embarrassment. Something needs to change.","FS: Have 2 Tix To Phish In Chula Vista @Phish #facevaluetickets #phish #facevalue  GO: https://t.co/dFdrpyaotp","RT @WKUPhiDelt: Come unwind from a busy week of class and kick off the weekend with a Phish Fry! 4:30-7:30 at the Phi Delt house. Cost is $\u2026","RT @phish: Tickets for Phish's July 15 &amp; 16 shows at The Gorge go on sale in fifteen minutes at 1PM ET: https://t.co/tEKLNjI5u7 https://t.c\u2026"],

"favorited":[false,false,false,false,false],

"favoriteCount":[0,0,0,0,0],

"replyToSN":["rAlexandria","phish","NA","NA","NA"],

"created":[1456521159,1456521114,1456521022,1456521016,1456520988],

"truncated":[false,false,false,false,false],

"replyToSID":["703326502629277696","703304948990222337","NA","NA","NA"],

"id":["703326837720662016","703326646074343424","703326261045829632","703326236722991105","703326119328686080"],

"replyToUID":["26152867","14503997","NA","NA","NA"],"statusSource":["<a href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Mobile Web (M5)</a>","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","<a href=\"http://cashortrade.org\" rel=\"nofollow\">CashorTrade - Face Value Tickets</a>","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>"],

"screenName":["rAlexandria","adamgelvan","CashorTrade","Kyle_Smith1087","timogrennell"],

"retweetCount":[0,0,0,2,5],

"isRetweet":[false,false,false,true,true],

"retweeted":[false,false,false,false,false],

"longitude":["NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"],

"latitude":["NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"]}
```

Comment: Use `dput` to post reproducible data object on which you are requesting advice. Post library calls for all packages with functions needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your code and don't have the issue you're describing. Are you using `library(twitteR)` and `library(jsonlite)`?

Here is the code, and a screenshot of it working

```
library(twitteR)
library(jsonlite)

phish <- searchTwitteR('phish', n = 5, lang = 'en')
phishdf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(phish, as.data.frame))

exportJson <-toJSON(phishdf)

write(exportJson, file = "./../phishdf.json")

## note the `txt` argument, as opposed to `file` used in the question
json_phishdf <- fromJSON(txt="./../phishdf.json")
```

[image]

Comment: awesome. I was not using jsonlite, wonder if that was part of the problem. Either that or changing file to txt worked. Thanks!